# combining for loop iterations into a single line and no match handling

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

Probably a very basic question but hoping someone can help out.

I have the following:

```
query = ['whole regular milk', 'gatorade is better', 'whole almond chocolate 
milk', 'chocolate milk']

types = ['whole', 'regular', 'chocolate' ]

new_list = []

for i in query:
    for k in types:
        regex_concat = r"\b" + k + r"\b"
        new_regex =  re.search(regex_concat,i)
        if (str(new_regex)) != 'None':
            print((new_regex.group()))
        else:
            print('no match')
```

who's output generates the following:

```
whole
regular
no match
no match
no match
no match
whole
no match
chocolate
no match
no match
chocolate
```

My ideal output would be:

```
whole | regular
Blank
whole | chocolate
chocolate
```

Questions:

I think I should be able to use the following to combine the output into a single line:

```
print((new_regex.group()), end= "|", flush=True)
```

which would give me:

```
whole|regular|no match
no match
no match
no match
whole|no match
chocolate|no match
no match
chocolate|
```

I can't seem to figure out how to net out to the requested output above.

Some additional notes--

The query list will be compiled from a pd DataFrame. From there, I would like to use the desired output, which I'd convert to a list > series, to map back to the pd DataFrame. This is why I'd like the blank row to still be present because the final output should look like this:

```
Query                         Type
whole regular milk            whole | regular
gatorade is better             
whole almond chocolate milk   whole | choclate  
chocolate milk                chocolate
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is already a datarframe, you can do the whole thing in the dataframe level:

```
import re

query = ['whole regular milk', 'gatorade is better',
         'whole almond chocolate milk', 'chocolate milk', 'wholes']

types = [{'type': t, 'regex': re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(t))}
         for t in ['whole', 'regular', 'chocolate']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Query': query})

def check(q):
    return ' | '.join(type_info['type'] for type_info in types
                      if type_info['regex'].findall(q))

df['Type'] = df['Query'].apply(check)

print(df)

#                           Query                Type
#  0           whole regular milk     whole | regular
#  1           gatorade is better                   
#  2  whole almond chocolate milk   whole | chocolate
#  3               chocolate milk           chocolate
#  4                       wholes
```

Comment: The reason I opted for regex is to be able to exact match the type as they’ll likely be variants in future iterations.  For example if I had wholes, who, hole in types would your solution match on the substring?

Comment: Also very new to python so do correct me if I’m way off.