# Iterate different Regular Expression Patterns over df Column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a df column with text in it and I'm trying to extract different date patterns from it.

This `df1` for example:

```
<index>    text    
0          My birthday is 10/23/89.
1          Christmas is on December 25th.
2          Thanksgiving of 11/2008 was the best.
```

The desired output is a 3rd column, called `dates`:

```
<index>    text                                  dates
0          My birthday is 10/23/89.               10/23/89
1          Christmas is on December 25.           25 December
2          Thanksgiving of 11/2008 was the best.  11/2008
```

To pull our the first date I write my first re expression, like this one:

df1['dates'] = (df1['text'].str.findall(r'\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4}'))

And that's where I get stuck.

I don't know/understand how to write multiple re expressions and not keep writing over what's already in the df1['dates'] column.

I'd like to run my next expression:

```
df1['dates'] = df1['text'].str.findall(r'(?:\d{1,2})?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]* (?:\d{1,2}, )?\d{4}')
```

How, or what is the best way, to see if `df['dates']` column is null and then try the next re expression?

I asked this earlier today and it got flagged as a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169725/combining-for-loop-iterations-into-a-single-line-and-no-match-handling) but I think DeepSpace thought I was a lot smarter than I really am, my question is much more basic than the one he answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
df['dates'] = df['text'].str.extract('.*?(\d+/\d+/?\d*).*?')


    text                                    dates
0   My birthday is 10/23/89.                10/23/89
1   Christmas is 12/25.                     12/25
2   Thanksgiving of 11/2008 was the best.   11/2008
```

With the added test case:

```
df['text'].str.extract('.*?(\d+/\d+/?\d*).*?|\
(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December \d+)', expand = False)\
.fillna('').sum(1)
```

And you get

```
0       10/23/89
1    December 25
2        11/2008
```

Comment: @Vaishiali thank you - this expression helps, but the real data set also has some months like 'Oct', 'October' so the real result set isn't all digits.  Therefore I think I still need to iterate over the dataset or get '|' operators to use multiple regular expressions on my data.

Comment: updated question for clarity and included a text month in my data to avoid confusion.  Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: @SDS, its difficult to write a precise regex for such cases but I have updated my answer anyway. Here I am trying to find two kinds of pattern, date in number format or Month name format and combine the two using sum on axis 1